# Apache redirect and PHP header

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create my own MVC structure in PHP, and I'm stuck on a conflict with an Apache rewrite rule and the PHP header() function. All requests are redirected to public/index.php file and in this index.php file I have header() function for displaying a static error template on some errors with `header('Location:')`.

My .htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

My .htaccess in the public/ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/errors/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The public/index.php file:

```
// Composer autoload file
// with bad filename to throw an error 
$sVendorDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload123.php';

if (file_exists($sVendorDir)) {
   require_once $sVendorDir;
} else {
   $sLogMsg = "Echec du chargement du fichier '$sVendorDir' (".__FILE__.":".__LINE__.")";
   error_log($sLogMsg);
   header("Location:http://www.project.dvp/templates/errors/erreur-technique.php");
   exit;
}
```

In my structure, the templates directory is located at the same level as the public directory (root/public/, root/templates/, also root/config/ and root/src/).

When I run this application, the browser says "the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will not succeed".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Personally, if an autoloader fails I would just throw an exception with a very explicit message. It should happen once or twice in the lifetime of a project, and it is a developer-level fix only.

Comment: Can you just point the entire web application's root to the public directory and not mess around with extra rewrites in htaccess?

Comment: _"In my structure, the templates directory is located at the same level as the public directory"_ - and what was the reasoning to put them there, outside of the public folder, in the first place? Because they don't _need_ to be publicly accessed, and are only supposed to be read by other script files? Well then your attempt to access them directly via HTTP now, is in contradiction to that. You should probably have an error handling script _in_ public then, that will read the necessary error page template file from the templates folder.

Comment: `/errors/erreur-...` - Straight Outta Babylon, huh :-)